# How to Recreate Travis CI Environment inside GitLab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm attempting to migrate a project from Travis CI to GitLab CI. I believe that the bash scripts shouldn't need to change - aside from swapping a few env variables provided by default. But, I've been unable to recreate the environment inside the GitLab yaml file.

```
sudo: required

services:
  - docker

env:
  DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION: 1.21.1

before_install:
  - sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
  - chmod +x docker-compose
  - sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin

script:
  - bash test-ci.sh $TRAVIS_BRANCH

after_success:
  - bash ./docker-push.sh
  - bash ./docker-deploy-stage.sh
  - bash ./docker-deploy-prod.sh
```

Here's my most recent failed attempt:

```
image: ubuntu:14.04

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION: 1.21.1

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common unzip python3 python3-pip docker.io libcgroup1 
  - pip3 install awscli
  - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
  - chmod +x docker-compose
  - sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - bash ./docker-push.sh
    - bash ./docker-deploy-stage.sh
    - bash ./docker-deploy-prod.sh
```

This is my first attempt to setup CI. Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you add some kind of error/what has failed?